# Embedded closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I ported a vanilla piece of code from Objective-C, where I liberally used nested closures, to Swift. Yet when I do it the brand new error:

> cannot reference a local function with captures from another local
>   function

comes out, like if this procedure were illegal: this is my piece of code:

```
func downloadCloseBuses(completionHandler: ((NSData) -> Void)!, errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)!){
    if let location=currentLocation{
        let urlString="http://backoffice.taxiprofessional.net/inarrivo/php/getBuses.php?latitude=\(location.coordinate.latitude)&longitude=\(location.coordinate.longitude)&viewStep=0.1";
        let url=NSURL(string:urlString)!
        let urlRequest=NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy:.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, reponse, error) in
            println("Task completed")
            if let isError=error{
                errorHandler(isError)
            } else {
                completionHandler(data)
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}

func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(
    completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {
        downloadCloseBuses(completionHandler: {(data, error) in
            if result == .NewData{
                tableView.reloadData()
                resetContentSize()
            }
            completionHandler(result)
        })
}
```

I get the error on the call to downloadCloseBuses.

Comment: You’ll have a much better chance of someone helping you if you post code other people can run (especially in a playground).  As it stands, it takes a lot to get your code to the point where it seems like it has a different error to yours (`downloadCloseBuses` is being called without a second closure).

Comment: What completionHandler and errorHandler are you using to your call to downloadCloseBuses?

Comment: "liberally used nested closures" ... I recommend against using that phrase as if you're bragging... you should be avoiding liberally nesting *anything*, and perhaps especially closures.

Comment: To me, closures are especially made for nesting with the completion of one completing another and so on. What I just discovered is that it is not good practice to combine blocks (at least in Objective-c) with recursion: I nearly extinguished all the memory of my iPhone in so doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact I was misled from other posting and the confusing error message: I changed a little stuff and everything works fine, this is the updated piece of code; of course I am new to Swift development and I do not distinguish very easily ropes from snakes:

```
func downloadCloseBuses(completionHandler: ((NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)!){
    if let location=currentLocation{
        let urlString="http://backoffice.taxiprofessional.net/inarrivo/php/getBuses.php?latitude=\(location.coordinate.latitude)&longitude=\(location.coordinate.longitude)&viewStep=0.1";
        let url=NSURL(string:urlString)!
        let urlRequest=NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy:.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, reponse, error) in
            println("Task completed")
            completionHandler(data, error)
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}

func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(
    completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {
        downloadCloseBuses({(data, error) in
            completionHandler(.NewData)
        })
}
```